# C++ introduce 'new' template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a reusable matrix class with the dimensions and type given in the template arguments. The struct itself is just:

```
template <unsigned int N, unsigned int M, typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    T elements[N* M];
};
```

When I tried to implement matrix multiplication, I came to a problem that I need to introduce new template arguments. The size of the original matrix is N * M. The size of the second matrix is L * N and the result matrix is N * K. So the multiply function would look something like:

```
Matrix<N, K, T> Multiply(const Matrix<L, N, T>& other) {... }
```

But then I need to create a template for the function, so calling would become `mat.Multiply<x, y>(mat2)`, which means that I have to specify things twice. Is there a way to avoid this? (something like `Matrix<N, unsigned int K, T>`)

Edit: I've tried this:

```
template <unsigned int K, unsigned int L>
Matrix<N, K, T> Multiply(const Matrix<L, N, T>& other)
```

And with this code I get an error saying no instance of function template matches the argument list:

```
Matrix<3, 2, int> mat;
Matrix<2, 3, int> mat2;
mat.Multiply(mat2)
```

By the way I'm using MSVC and Visual Studio.

Comment: I think you missed the point about templates - they help genericize data types not parameterize values

Comment: It seemed logical to just specify the size of the matrix too, as it's fixed. I guess I was wrong?

Comment: @PeterLenkefi Having the dimensions of the matrix in the type is a good idea. It allows you to restrict invalid operations at compile time.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi You specify the size whitin a function (for example in a constructor, since you are yousing c++). In template parameters you specify the generalized types.

Comment: @Lasoloz This doesn't really make any sense. OP's idea is perfectly fine. All that is missing is for the multiplication function to be a template.

Comment: @juanchopanza As said in the first comment, templates are for generalizing data. Yes, you can use other methods and do your stuff in new ways, but I think the templates are not intended for parameters, and you can confuse other developers in future.

Comment: @Lasoloz You make even less sense now.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK, I guess you are right. I just never saw STL classes having parameters in template part.

Comment: @Lasoloz _" I just never saw STL classes"_ There's `std::array<typename T,size_t N>` just to name one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, I forgot about this. So, just unconsider my previous comments, probably it's to early for me to watch SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so calling would become `mat.Multiply<x, y>(mat2)`

If the multiplication member function were a function template like so

```
template <unsigned int N, unsigned int M, typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    template <unsigned int  L>
    Matrix<N, L, T> Multiply(const Matrix<M, L, T>& other) {... }
    T elements[N * M];
};
```

then template argument deduction allows you to call the function like this:

```
mat.Multiply(mat2)
```

Note: you should probably consider implementing a non-member `operator*` too, to allow for this:

```
auto mat3 = mat * mat2;
```

Comment: I've tried something like this but the compiler does not really like it.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi I got the dimensions of the `other` matrix wrong, and I think you did too. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that `Multiply` is also template.
Note that `K == L` for a multiplication.

```
template <unsigned int N, unsigned int M, typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    template <unsigned int K>
    Matrix<N, K, T> Multiply(const Matrix<M, K, T>& other) const {/*..*/}

    T elements[N* M];
};
```

In the call, all template argument are deducible so you can call it that way:

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 4;
    const int M = 5;
    const int K = 6;
    using T = float;
    Matrix<N, M, T> rhs;
    Matrix<M, K, T> lhs;
    Matrix<N, K, T> res = rhs.Multiply(lhs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually missed the fact that K == L!